# Where these arguments are defined?

Tags: menus, navigation

I want to make 2-line navi, and found this code.

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'description_in_nav_el', 10, 4);

function description_in_nav_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args)
{
    return preg_replace('/(<a.*?>[^<]*?)</', '$1' . "<span>{$item->post_content}</span><", $item_output);
}
```

http://pastebin.com/Fw3e0wqC

Where come from these arguments `$item_output` and `$item`?
I know `$item_output` is nav_menu html source and $item is nav_menu, but I don't know in which function the html are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look on ow [WordPress Plugin Api](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L169) works.

When you add a filter, the function that hook into that filter receive the argument from the function: `apply_filters`.

This function pass at least one argument, but can pass more, and always aspect a value returned.

So if you can write

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'description_in_nav_el', 10, 4 );
```

is because somewhere in the code there is a line that appear something like:

```
$output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
```

So the argument you can use, are passed to your function via `apply_filters` and they are generated in the function that contain that line.

when you want to know more on a hook, first play where to see, is Codex, however not all hooks can be founded there, in that case best place where look is **code**.

I think you use a software to write your code, and most probably that software have a search feature among all files in a folder<sup>1</sup>, so once you know what to search:

> apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el'

try yourself, you'll find the file [`/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` at line 169](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L169) contain just the line I posted above, inside the method `start_el` of the class `Walker_Nav_Menu`.

<sup>1</sup> *If you are familiar and use any Unix SO, of course you'll have easier life using `grep`, but in that case, you already know it...*